# Testing changes in a generated Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a series of Jenkins jobs that are generated via Jobs DSL that are dependent upon one another.

For example:

```
Jobs:
   Build package
   Test package
   Deploy package
```

I'd like to test a change in one of those jobs, i.e. the `Test Package` job. I have a branch and a PR in the seed repo.

My only means of testing this right now is to edit the job and build it manually in the UI and hope that it doesn't break anything, I could also merge the PR without testing it and risk breaking the production workflow.

Neither of the above options are good. I'd like to isolate my changes so that I can test the job from my branch or PR. Should I switch to using a Pipeline or is there a way to use Jobs DSL off of a PR or branch (like `develop`)?

Comment: If the jobs are dependent it may look like they are a part of one bigger flow. In this case, you should definitely switch to pipeline. If you switch to a Multi-branch pipeline, your Jenkinsfile sits together with the code, so you can make a branch and test your changes in your branch, and this will not influence other branches a bit.